# iPhone OpenGl render text

Tags: iphone, opengl, text, render, frame-rate

Does anyone know how can i render a string on the iphone? Its for displaying my frame per second with =p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in way of rendering text in OpenGL but two more or less common techniques: Rendering the glyphs using geometry (less common) or using texture mapping (far more common). For your case texture mapping would be very easy: Set up a CGBitmapContext and render the text using Quartz. Then upload the image in the previously generated texture using glTexSubImage2D.

On the iPhone you could also just put a UILabel on top of you OpenGL view and let UIKit do the rendering. In my application this did not hit performance at all (even though Apple claims it does).

Comment: how do i layer the UILabel on top of the openGL view?

Comment: Just add it as a subview: `[myGLView addSubview:myUILabel];`

Comment: AAAAAH!!  A widget on top of your subview/??

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Texture2D and the initWithString method to draw text in OpenGL. See the crash landing example that is included in the iphone sdk.

You could also use a UILabel and have it on top of the opengl layer.

Comment: do u know where can i get the font needed?

Answer (score 3):

As said before, Texture2D is a good idea, but Crash Landing was removed from a lot of places in Apple, what you could do , is download the Cocos2d , and then extract the Texture2D class provided there ( it's the same class provided by Apple, but with a couple of more things )
[Cocos 2D for iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/)